# Pagination of Multiple RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, pagination, android-nestedscrollview

Can any help me to do pagination of multiple recyclerview inside NestedScrollView.

I have a two recyclerview insid NestedScrollView.

I want to perform pagination for both recyclerview. can any one help me to achieve same.

Thank you